Длина сегмента(видео) и время отклика
Разбираюсь как работать с dash
https://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/jsdoc/index.html
Разбиваю видео на сегменты, длина каждого 10секунд.
Пришла идея в голову, но не знаю верна ли и стоит ли так делать.
Если первый сегмент сделать к примеру 3 секунды, а последующие по 10 секунды.
При первом открытии web страницы, быстрее запустится плеер? То есть время отклика сократиться? Вес файла будет в трое меньше...
